# How to solve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error on trying to print appended object in an array?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

When I run my code it gives me an error as follows:

```
 Exception in thread "main" tony
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at tt.main(tt.java:17)
```

The code is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class tt {


   static int oldAge[];
   static Integer ages[];
   static ArrayList<Integer> ageObject;

public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("tony");
    setAges();


        System.out.println(ages[1].intValue());
    System.out.println(oldAge[2]);



   }

   public static void setAges(){


    oldAge = new int[3];

     oldAge[0] = 50;
     oldAge[1] = 60;
     oldAge[2] = 70;

     ages = new Integer[1];
     ages[0] = 50;

     ageObject = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ages));

 for(int x =0; x < oldAge.length; x++){

  if(oldAge[x] == 60){
    ageObject.add(oldAge[x]);
 }
  else if(oldAge[x] == 56){
    ageObject.add((Integer)(oldAge[x]));
 }
  else if(oldAge[x] == 70){
    ageObject.add((Integer)(oldAge[x]));
 }



       }

     }

  }
```

I want the code to to print the newly added value of ages which is supposed to be 60.

Comment: Why did you say `NullPointerException` in your title if you are actually getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
System.out.println(ages[1].intValue());
```

is incorrect. `ages` is exactly one element. It should be

```
System.out.println(ages[0].intValue());
```

with no other changes I get

```
tony
50
70
```

To get `60`, you would need to print the second element of `oldAge`. Like,

```
System.out.println(oldAge[1]);
```